# Java HSB color model: colors changing with brightness?

Tags: java, colors, color-management

Why does altering brightness changes color in **HSB** color model? Here's my code:

```
for (int y=0; y<height; y++)
    for (int x=0; x<width; x++) {
        Color pix = image.getPixel(x, y);
            float[] hsb = new float[3];
            Color.RGBtoHSB(pix.getRGB(),pix.getGreen(),pix.getBlue(),hsb);
            Color newColor = new Color(Color.HSBtoRGB(hsb[0], hsb[1],(float)0.5));
                image.setPixel(x, y, newColor);
        }
```

The code assigns value of 0.5 to brightness of each pixel in image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in your call to `Color.RGBtoHSB`.

You wrote:

```
Color.RGBtoHSB(pix.getRGB(),pix.getGreen(),pix.getBlue(),hsb);
```

You probably wanted:

```
Color.RGBtoHSB(pix.getRed(),pix.getGreen(),pix.getBlue(),hsb);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I figured out `brightness` does not work in the same way as `luminance`.